# How To Create an Add-To-Cart Button with Quantity Controls (Plus/Minus Counter) Buttons?

Tags: android

I want to create Add to cart Button with Quantity Controls like Swiggy and actually I already did it with Button using `leftDrawable` and `rightDrawable` properties in xml. But I want to know some other perfect solutions.

For Reference Look At The Attached Image.

[image]

Comment: Try to come up with some code or logic to implement this. Stackover flow platform is not there to create a code, It is there to improvise/rework on your logic/code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will look more beautifull...

```
      <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkboxrel"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="9dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/less"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/light"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="9dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/substract" />


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/prnumber"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/more"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/light"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="9dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/add" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do like leftDrawable and rightDrawable, click events you cannot capture exactly what user click. Simply you can create horizontal Linear layout and keep all elements horizontally.

For example,

```
<linearLayout
  orientation ='horizontal'>
 <button text='+'/>
 <textView text='0'/>
 <button text='-'/>
</linearLayout>
```